# how to pass dictionary object from ajax to controller class in play framework

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, playframework-2.0

I have dynatree in my view page, I want to save the current state of the tree on every drag and drop operation, The problem is I am unable to pass that dict object to the controller. The code of ajax is below :

```
 onDrop: function(node, sourceNode, hitMode, ui, draggable) {
        /** This function MUST be defined to enable dropping of items on
         * the tree.
         */
        logMsg("tree.onDrop(%o, %o, %s)", node, sourceNode, hitMode);
        sourceNode.move(node, hitMode);
        //save state to backend
     var currentTree = $("#tree").dynatree("getTree").toDict();
            $.post("/Application.java", { recieved: currentTree},
               function(data) {
                 $("#output").html(data);
             });


         //expand the drop target
        sourceNode.expand(true);
      },
```

I have written a method in java that is getting that dictionary object.. But It is giving me error in route file. Error : not found: type Dictionary in this line

POST     /hello/:dict                      controllers.Application.check(dict:Dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

You have many problems in your code.

First, for the main issue, the `routes` files can not be compiled because it does know your class `Dictionary`. So you have to tell the file the qualified name of this class (package + class):

```
POST /hello/:dict controllers.Application.check(dict:package.to.Dictionary)
```

But AFAIK, it may not work either, because the dynamic part of the Url (`dict`) should be printable in the Url, because, you'll have to call the Url with your dict encoded into it. Let say: `/hello/thisIsMyDict`

So your best option is to remove the dynamic part of the Url in the routes file:

```
POST /hello/ controllers.Application.check()
```

Then, in your action, get the body parameters using a [DynamicForm](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/java/play/data/DynamicForm.html) for instance:

```
public static Result check() {
   DynamicForm myForm = form().bindFromRequest();
   String dict = myForm.get("recieved");
   // convert the string to your Dictionary object
   ...
}
```

And finally, your javascript code should look like:

```
var currentTree = $("#tree").dynatree("getTree").toDict();
$.post("@controllers.routes.Application.check()", { recieved: currentTree},
     function(data) {
        $("#output").html(data);
     });
```

Comment: I have done the above solution, I am trying to print that string but its printing null.. Could you please tell me how to convert this string into dictionary object ?